# How can I set border-radius on table head in Bootstrap 5?

Tags: html, css

I use Bootstrap 5 for table as shown as but when I set border radius on `table-dark` class it does not change the border of the `thead` element. How can I do that??

```css
.table-dark {
  border-radius: 9px;
}

.table>thead {
  border-radius: 9px;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.0.2/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet">


<table class="table table-dark table-hover">
  <thead>
    <tr>
      <th scope="col">#</th>
      <th scope="col">First</th>
      <th scope="col">Last</th>
      <th scope="col">Handle</th>
    </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody>
    <tr>
      <th scope="row">1</th>
      <td>Mark</td>
      <td>Otto</td>
      <td>@mdo</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <th scope="row">2</th>
      <td>Jacob</td>
      <td>Thornton</td>
      <td>@fat</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <th scope="row">3</th>
      <td>Larry</td>
      <td>the Bird</td>
      <td>@twitter</td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```css
table {
 border-radius: 9px;
 overflow: hidden /* add this */
}

/* Or do this */

thead th:first-child {
 border-top-left-radius: 9px;
}

thead th:last-child {
 border-top-right-radius: 9px;
}

tbody tr:last-child :first-child {
 border-bottom-left-radius: 9px;
}

tbody tr:last-child :last-child {
 border-bottom-right-radius: 9px;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.0.2/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet">


<table class="table table-dark table-hover">
  <thead>
    <tr>
      <th scope="col">#</th>
      <th scope="col">First</th>
      <th scope="col">Last</th>
      <th scope="col">Handle</th>
    </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody>
    <tr>
      <th scope="row">1</th>
      <td>Mark</td>
      <td>Otto</td>
      <td>@mdo</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <th scope="row">2</th>
      <td>Jacob</td>
      <td>Thornton</td>
      <td>@fat</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <th scope="row">3</th>
      <td>Larry</td>
      <td>the Bird</td>
      <td>@twitter</td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```